# How to check if UIPasteboard has images on iOS < 10?

Tags: ios, uipasteboard

How do I check if a `UIPasteboard` has images on iOS < 10?

Comment: Check if the `images` property is empty or not.

Comment: Empty or `nil`?

Answer (score 3):

**There are two ways of identifying this:**

1. Check if [`pasteboard.hasImages`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1829411-hasimages?language=objc) property returns true or not
2. Check the [`pasteboard.images.count`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1622086-images?language=objc) property

Comment: [Apple says:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1829411-hasimages?language=objc) "**Do not use the image or  images properties to determine whether a pasteboard contains image data**, because doing so consumes resources needlessly."

Comment: Thats right but there is no other alternative for this right now

Comment: You have the alternative in your first approach. pasteboard.hasImages